# How do i check the reaction content in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a ticket system. And i want a confirmation with the `/close` command. But how do i do that? I tried it wit an if statement but it didnt work.
This is what i have:

```py
@bot.command(name='Close', aliases=['close'])
async def close(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.name.startswith('ticket'):
        msg = 'The ticket is closed. If you aren\'t done yet react to this message with , if you are react with ️'
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Closed ticket', description=msg)
        message = await ctx.send(content=None, embed=embed)
        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('️')
        await ctx.message.channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, send_messages=False)
        reaction = await bot.wait_for('reaction')
        if reaction.content == '️':
            countdown = await ctx.send('**Ticket will be closed in 10 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 9 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 8 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 7 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 6 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 5 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 4 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 3 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 2 seconds**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await countdown.edit(content='**Ticket will be closed in 1 second**')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await ctx.message.channel.delete()
        if reaction.content == '':
            await ctx.send('**Ticket reopened**')
            await ctx.message.channel.set_permissions(ctx.autor, send_messages=True)
    else:
        await ctx.send('This isnt a ticket')
```

And i didn't even get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

When waiting for a reaction to be added, you should use `"reaction_add"` instead of just `"reaction"`:

```py
@bot.command(...)
async def close(ctx):
    # Code

    # A check is usually encouraged when in a public channel,
    # but for a private channel with just one or two members, it should be fine
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add")
    # Do some stuff
```

Two values are actually being returned from this `wait_for`, as seen in the [documentation's example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) - `reaction`, and `user`.

Additionally, the `discord.Reaction` object has no `content` attribute.
You'll actually be looking for `str(reaction)` instead:

[image]

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction)
- [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User)

Comment: Thanks!! You helped me again (-:. It finally worked thank you so much!