# 'Bot' object has no attribute 'wait_for_reaction'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

error: `'Bot' Has No Attribute Called 'wait_for_reaction'`, Here's The Code:

```
if int(pp) >= 19:
        gh = await message.send('''
Your Number Is Higher Or Is 20... Click ⬆ To Continue''')
        await gh.add_reaction("⬆")
        await bot.wait_for_reaction('⬆', gh)
```

btw `bot = command.Bot()`

Comment: Please include your definition of `bot`, the classes it extends from, and the libraries you are using (& versions if possible)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for):

```py
await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", timeout=180, check=lambda payload: payload.member == ctx.author and str(payload.emoji) == "⬆")
```

Answer (score 1):

`bot.wait_for_reaction` is no longer a part of discord.py and has been deprecated. Instead, you should be using [`bot.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), making the bot 'wait for' a reaction, and checking if the reaction's author is the author of the message. Do view a further explanation in the revised code below:

```py
if int(pp) >= 19:
        gh = await message.send('''
Your Number Is Higher Or Is 20... Click ⬆ To Continue''')
        await gh.add_reaction("⬆")

        # New code starts here #

        # Define your check
        # Checks if the reaction author is the author of the message
        # and if the reaction emoji is '⬆'
        def check(reaction, user):
                return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '⬆'

        try:
                reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check,timeout=10)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError: # That way the bot doesn't wait forever for a reaction
                await message.send("Ran out of time, interaction ended")
                return
        if reaction: 
                # 'if statement' is regarded if the given reaction is valid (and not None)
                # Continue with the rest of your code
```

[image: Above working]

**Questions like this**:

- [Reaction Check with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090668/reaction-check-with-discord-py) - SO
- [Discord.py detecting reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65082883/discord-py-detecting-reactions) - SO
- [How do i check the reaction content in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416842/how-do-i-check-the-reaction-content-in-discord-py) - SO